# How do I lock a field on Node Edit?

Tags: 7, entities

I want to create a node field that is only editable upon node creation. Once the node has been created, the field of that node will no longer be editable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are ready for the *do it in code* road, you can implement [`hook_field_access()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.api.php/function/hook_field_access/7), something like

```
function MODULE_field_access($op, $field, $entity_type, $entity, $account) {
  if ($op == 'edit' && $entity_type == 'node' && $field['field_name'] == 'field_of_interest') {
    // The nid property of a new node is empty
    return empty($entity->nid);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here you go: the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module, which (as stated on its project page) "*... allows site administrators to set field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.*"

Comment: How does field permissions module help on OP's question? As far as I know, you cannot disable the field "after node creation"